# how does inheritance work in java when a method in abstract class call a method that has been overriden?

Tags: java, inheritance

class A is abstract and has methods aa and bb.
class B extends A and overrides bb. 
method aa in A calls bb.

does it call class B bb or class A bb?

Comment: It calls class `B`'s version.

Comment: You could try it out very easily.

Comment: `"method aa in calls bb."`, in *what*?

Comment: I downvoted this since it can be so easily tested just by using some `System.out.println` in the different methods.

Comment: It was a real life example that wasn’t behaving as I expected so I simplified scenario when I asked the Q. Anyway it calls B’s bb.  I was looking st wrong thing in my real code that explains why I saw diff results.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Easy to answer beginner's questions are welcome on Stackoverflow. The real issue I see here is that this is likely a duplicate, but I don't have time right now to check.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I agree with you but at the same time you should be able to do some research on your own no matter what experience you have and for me that was lacking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried it out. It calls class B version of bb.